# SQL: mix join with case and NULL

Tags: sql, join, null, case

Pretty simple, what's the best way to fix the `NULL` filtering below, since the `=` operand doesn't work with `NULL`?

The `Key2`, when `Data1=-1`, is trying to do a `Key2=NULL` which is not selecting `NULL` values.

```
LEFT JOIN myReferenceTable
    on myReferenceTable.Key1 = myDataTable.FKey1
    and myReferenceTable.Key2 =
    CASE
        WHEN myDataTable.Data1 = -1 THEN NULL
        ELSE myDataTable.Data3 - myDataTable.Data4 
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's - (I'm computing the value from the columns Data3 and Data4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap out your case statement using ANDs / ORs

```
LEFT JOIN myReferenceTable
    on myReferenceTable.Key1 = myDataTable.FKey1
    and ((myDataTable.Data1 = -1 AND myReferenceTable.Key2 IS NULL) 
           OR (myDataTable.Data1 != -1 AND myReferenceTable.Key2 = myDataTable.Data3 - myDataTable.Data4))
```

Comment: Thanks... should be an easier way :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, you need to use the "null-safe equal" operator.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

> <=>
>
> NULL-safe equal. This operator performs an equality comparison like
>   the = operator, but returns 1 rather than NULL if both operands are
>   NULL, and 0 rather than NULL if one operand is NULL.

```
mysql> SELECT 1 <=> 1, NULL <=> NULL, 1 <=> NULL;
        -> 1, 1, 0
mysql> SELECT 1 = 1, NULL = NULL, 1 = NULL;
        -> 1, NULL, NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are trying to join the ReferenceTable to the DataTable on Key1 & Key2, (Key1 is a direct match, and Key2 matches to the difference between Data3 and Data4) but you want to explicitly filter out rows where Data1 = -1.  It seems that you may be wanting to also return a NULL if Data1 = -1, but what gets returned will depend on what's in your SELECT statement.  We're talking about the Join here, and you're doing a Left Join which tells me you want all rows from myRerenceTable returned, whether of not there are matches in myDataTable.  Having said that, I would write the Join as:

```
    LEFT JOIN myReferenceTable
        on myReferenceTable.Key1 = myDataTable.FKey1
        and myDataTable.Data1 <> -1
        AND myReferenceTable.Key2 = myDataTable.Data3 - myDataTable.Data4
```